# unity error: UnityLinker.exe did not run properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want get android build in unity but I have below errors:

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.30f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe -out="E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip" -x="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.30f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Whitelists\Core.xml" -x "E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\..\platform_native_link.xml" -x "C:\Users\Zahra\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp53472f88.tmp" -d "E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --include-unity-root-assembly="E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" --include-unity-root-assembly="E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll" --dotnetruntime=il2cpp --dotnetprofile=unityaot --use-editor-options --include-directory=E:\game\unityProjects\balloon2\BallonsMAtch3\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed --rule-set=Conservative

stdout:
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Mono.Linker.Steps.XmlResolutionException: Failed to process XML description: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.30f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Whitelists\Core.xml ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.ProcessType(TypeDefinition type, XPathNavigator nav)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.ProcessTypes(AssemblyDefinition assembly, XPathNodeIterator iterator)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, XPathNodeIterator iterator)
   at Unity.Linker.Steps.Resolution.UnityResolveFromXmlStep.ProcessAssemblies(LinkContext context, XPathNodeIterator iterator)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.Process()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.ResolveFromXmlStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.Run()
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling()
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()
stderr:

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1, String&, String&, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:192)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String[], String[], String, String, String&, String&, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, IEnumerable`1, BuildTargetGroup, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:124)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable, String, String[], String[], String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, RuntimeClassRegistry, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:324)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssemblies(String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, RuntimeClassRegistry, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:216)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:203)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

My unity version is 2018.4.30f1. I can get build in other projects and just this project has problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing API compatibility to 4x

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this in our project because of a silly error. The Unity Project name (aka directory name) had a comma in it. Removing the project from Unity Hub, renaming the directory and re-adding to Unity Hub fixed this error.

Comment: many thanks, bro. waste a lot of time to fix it. you saved my day!